# POP3 client doesn't receive greeting from server in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, pop3, recv

I am trying to write a simple POP3 client which would connect to the pop.gmail.com server and receive a greeting from it. But after connecting to the server I am unable to recieve any information from it. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#define DEFAULTSIZE 512

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct hostent *remoteHost;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char server_reply[DEFAULTSIZE];
    int recv_size;

    //Initializing winsock
    printf("Initialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Initialising Winsock f ailed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    remoteHost = gethostbyname("pop.gmail.com");

    //Creating socket
    if((s = socket(remoteHost->h_addrtype, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Initializing address
    memcpy(&addr.sin_addr, remoteHost->h_addr_list[0], remoteHost->h_length);
    addr.sin_family = remoteHost->h_addrtype;
    addr.sin_port = htons( 995 );

    //Connecting socket to the address
    if(connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0){
        printf("Connecting socket failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket connected\n");

    //Receiving information from the server
    if((recv_size = recv(s, server_reply, DEFAULTSIZE, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        printf("Receiving information failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Size of how much information has been received: %d\n", recv_size);
    for(int i = 0; i < recv_size; ++i){
        printf("%c", server_reply[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //Checking if socket is connected
    int error_code;
    int error_code_size = sizeof(error_code);
    getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&error_code, &error_code_size);
    printf("Socket state: %d\n", error_code);

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand from RFC specification, I should receive a greeting from a server something along the lines with "+OK POP3 server ready", but I do not receive anything at all (recv_size = 0 and error_code = 0). I have tried connecting to different servers with the same results... Am I missing out on something from POP3 documentation or is there something wrong with the code?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're forgetting a small, teensy-weensy detail: port 995 uses TLS/SSL encryption. Which means that you will need to use some kind of an SSL library to negotiate a TLS session, before having any kind of hope of talking to the remote server in any meaningful way.

Comment: To talk to a POP server unencrypted, use port 110. Otherwise, get hold of a SSL/TLS library.

Comment: pop.gmail.com doesn't connect on 110 port. So I believe I'll have to try to look for some SSL library. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @Justinas Daukša [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org) is a place to start..

Comment: Also note that once you do securely connect to Gmail's port using SSL/TLS encryption, you then have to authenticate your user account before you can access your emails. If you have 2-factor authentication enabled on your Gmail account, you have to implement OAuth 2.0 authentication alongside your POP3 code, or you have to generate an app-specific password in your Gmail account settings for use with POP3. Otherwise, you have to enable "less secure apps" in your Gmail account in order to use your real Gmail password. Isn't security fun? (NOT!)